# Resolving PostgresSQL install on Mac Pro (macOS Monterey)

Tags: macos, postgresql-14

I need help connecting my postgreSQL14 EDB Download to terminal on mac.

Download was successful but... when I type psql at terminal as below I receive this message:

```
~ » psql                                              
zsh: command not found: psql
```

I have tried brew install also problematic. Removed.

What can I do to connect this?

---

Progress update:
edited .zshrc file to include:
#PostgresSQL 14 Path
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/14/bin:$PATH

To access .zshrc open at your mac your user name in Mac Finder.
Then hit Cmd + Shift + .(period) to see hidden files then open .zshrc with code editor amend save & exit.

if psql is not recognised at cli then enter one of the following:
psql -U postgres
sudo -u postgres psql

enter your password when asked.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install PostgreSQL. If you've got homebrew, use that method. If all that seems unfamiliar, you can check out [this link](https://dyclassroom.com/howto-mac/how-to-install-postgresql-on-mac-using-homebrew) which will lead you through the process from scratch.